# How to check if webdriver (Using selenium grid) instance is available and reachable

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid2

I see this error in my test logs:
WebDriverException: Session [id] was terminated due to FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED.

I am using webdriver with grid configuration {HUB is in Boston and node is in London}

How to check if my driver instance is reachable ?
Using (null != driver) does not handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you can fix at your client code side.

As per the documentation [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#hub-diagnostic-messages) below is when your issue occurs.

`FORWARDING_TO_NODE_FAILED   The hub was unable to forward to the node. Out of memory errors/node stability issues or network problems`

Sometime back I wrote a blog post wherein I explained how to go about building a "Self Healing" Grid. You can read it [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/building-a-self-maintaining-grid-environment/) to understand how you can avert these kind of problems (especially memory leaks)

If you are looking for some ready made solutions which demonstrates and uses this concept, take a look at the following :

- SeLion Enhanced Grid - http://paypal.github.io/SeLion/html/documentation.html#selion-grid
- Selenium Grid Extras - https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras

Comment: Thanks Krishnan, I am looking for a simpler solution. e.g a method that checks if Hub can communicate with Node . p.s. HubManager.checkNode(firefox, availableForTest).

Comment: The new session is a different request and all the other commands are different requests. Until you create a new session (which happens when you create a new RemoteWebDriver), the hub wouldn't really know which node is going to take its request. So what you are asking for as a simple api is not something that can be done.. (atleast not to the best of my knowledge)